# Rust - unsafely share between threads a mutable data without mutex

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex, unsafe

How can old school multi-threading (no wrapping mutex) can be achieve in Rust? And why is it undefined behavior?

I have to build a highly concurrent physic simulation. I am supposed to do it in C, but I chose Rust (I really needed higher level features).

By using Rust, I should opt for a safe communication between threads, however, I must use a **mutable buffer shared between the threads**. (actually, I have to implement different techniques and benchmark them)

**First approach**

1. Use `Arc<Data>` to share non-mutable state.
2. Use `transmute` to promote `&` to `&mut` when needed.

It was straightforward but the compiler would prevent this from compiling even with `unsafe` block. It is because the compiler can apply optimizations knowing this data is supposedly non-mutable (maybe cached and never updated, not an expert about that).

This kind of optimizations can be stopped by `Cell` wrapper and others.

**Second approach**

1. Use `Arc<UnsafeCell<Data>>`.
2. Then `data.get()` to access data.

This does not compile either. The reason is that `UnsafeCell` is not `Send`. The solution is to use `SyncUnsafeCell` but it is unstable for the moment (1.66), and the program will be compile and put to production on a machine with only the stable version.

**Third approach**

1. Use `Arc<Mutex<Data>>`.
2. At the beginning of each threads:

   - Lock the mutex.
   - Keep a `*mut` by coercing a `&mut`.
   - Release the mutex.
3. Use the `*mut` when needed

I haven't tried this one yet, but even if it compiles, is it safe (not talking about data race) as it would be with `SyncUnsafeCell` ?

PS: The values concurrently mutated are just `f32`, there are absolutely no memory allocation or any complex operations happening concurrently. Worst case scenario, I have scrambled some `f32`.

Comment: "Is it safe?" Looks like [UB](https://predr.ag/blog/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-undefined-behavior/). Other than that: You can probably just copy [the implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.66.1/src/core/cell.rs.html#2094-2099) of `SyncUnsafeCell` from `std`, there doesn't seem to be anything magic about it. Btw, how about a `Vec<AtomicU32>` (because there's no `AtomicF32`), and r/w to it through `f32::from`/`to_bits`?

Comment: So if you're doing a "highly concurrent physic simulation" then what value does such a thing have if the results are _wrong_?  If you have threading/concurrency errors, eventually you're going to stomp on yourself.  So what was the point of going through that effort?  I know this sounds dismissive, but I'm serious: where's the upside here?  Spend the time to do it right.

Comment: Perhaps the question devolves down to:  "how to share a mutable unsynchronized buffer between threads without introducing race conditions"?

Comment: I think @Caesar is onto something here. On most targets, `AtomicU32` is zero-overhead and gives you exactly what you need.

Comment: Does `AtomicU32` really have zero-overhead when fetching and writing back ? That could be the best approach indeed.

Comment: @uben See the assembly in my answer

Comment: My knowledge on this is a bit fuzzy, but calling `AtomicU32` zero-overhead is a bit misleading, I think: If it does incur synchronization overhead between cores through the cache consistency mechanisms, it can be quite heavy. For example, several concurrent threads incrementing the same `AtomicU32` will only get a few 1000 increments done per second, iirc.

Comment: Of course. No over-head *in comparison with* regular `f32`. Any atomic op has to be... well, atomic.

Comment: @Caesar That is also true for normal `f32`, though. For example, if you access the same `uint32_t` in C++ from multiple threads, you also get the cache consistency slowdown. It's more of an architectural thing than a code overhead. If you look at what it compiles to, there is zero difference between using an atomic and a normal `f32`.

Comment: @Caesar *"only get a few 1000 increments"* - I strongly disagree: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6747d1e950901dd9575d8be56d4b9f21. Try it out on your own machine. I have an 8 core machine and get >50 million/second. For reference: I get ~141 mil/s with one thread and ~51 mil/s with 8 threads on my 8 thread machine. So yes, there is an overhead, but by far not as bad as you make it seem. And it most likely only occurs if you actually access the same variable from multiple cores; OP does not intend to do that much.

Comment: Based on their description it's most likely a space partitioned simulation, and every thread only accesses its own values, plus some border exchange.

Comment: @Caesar So what does `AtomicU32` actually mean compared to `u32`, if `u32` is already atomic? Two things: volaticity (meaning: cannot be optimized into registers) and prevention of instruction reordering (hence the `Ordering` parameters). Apart of that, `load` and `store` is identical between `AtomicU32` and `u32`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: There are probably many ways to solve this, this is just one of them, based on the idea of @Caesar.

Two main points of this post:

- You can use `AtomicU32` to share `f32` between threads without any performance penalty (given an architecture where `u32` is already atomic)
- You can use `std::thread::scope` to avoid the overhead of `Arc`.

```rust
use std::{
    fmt::Debug,
    ops::Range,
    sync::atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering},
};

struct AtomicF32(AtomicU32);
impl AtomicF32 {
    pub fn new(val: f32) -> Self {
        Self(AtomicU32::new(val.to_bits()))
    }
    pub fn load(&self, order: Ordering) -> f32 {
        f32::from_bits(self.0.load(order))
    }
    pub fn store(&self, val: f32, order: Ordering) {
        self.0.store(val.to_bits(), order)
    }
}
impl Debug for AtomicF32 {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        self.load(Ordering::Relaxed).fmt(f)
    }
}

fn perform_action(data: &Vec<AtomicF32>, range: Range<usize>) {
    for value_raw in &data[range] {
        let mut value = value_raw.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
        value *= 2.5;
        value_raw.store(value, Ordering::Relaxed);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = (1..=10)
        .map(|v| AtomicF32::new(v as f32))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("Before: {:?}", data);

    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|| perform_action(&data, 0..5));
        s.spawn(|| perform_action(&data, 5..10));
    });

    println!("After: {:?}", data);
}
```

```
Before: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
After: [2.5, 5.0, 7.5, 10.0, 12.5, 15.0, 17.5, 20.0, 22.5, 25.0]
```

---

To demonstrate how leightweight this is, [here is what this compiles to](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/h6hePhj4o):

```rust
use std::{
    sync::atomic::{AtomicU32, Ordering},
};

pub struct AtomicF32(AtomicU32);
impl AtomicF32 {
    fn load(&self, order: Ordering) -> f32 {
        f32::from_bits(self.0.load(order))
    }
    fn store(&self, val: f32, order: Ordering) {
        self.0.store(val.to_bits(), order)
    }
}

pub fn perform_action(value_raw: &AtomicF32) {
    let mut value = value_raw.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
    value *= 2.5;
    value_raw.store(value, Ordering::Relaxed);
}
```

```
.LCPI0_0:
        .long   0x40200000
example::perform_action:
        movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rdi]
        mulss   xmm0, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0]
        movss   dword ptr [rdi], xmm0
        ret
```

---

Note that while this contains zero undefined behaviour, it still is the programmer's responsibility to avoid read-modify-write race conditions.

Comment: On both x86-64 and ARM, relaxed ordering store and loads are equivalent to non atomic store and loads. On x86-64, acquire load and some release stores are also free.